# Cursor with result from multiple content providers - Android

Tags: android

I want to query two different content providers:

MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

and

MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

First I need to query the "MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI" so that I can get a cursor to all images that were added after a specific date. I know now how to do this. The problem is with the thumbnails. I also need to query the "MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI" for obtaining the thumbnail images so that I can show them in a listview.  This is were I somehow need to combine the result from the two queries because I only want the Thumbnails for the Images that were added after a specific date. But the "MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails" doesn't have information about when the image was added. It only has an ID to the original image in "MediaStore.Images.Media".

So, to sum up what I need help with:

I need to get a cursor that contains the following columns:

MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID,

MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID,

MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA,

MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,

MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN

How can this be done?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you will manually need to do the join and pour the results into a `MatrixCursor` (if you are sure that you really need a `Cursor`) or some other data structure.

Comment: and this is because he has no access to the DB itself :-( i encountered several times issue like that when content providers don't give you the information you need resolving into manual data processing and memory consumption...

Answer (score 3):

You can select the data from one provider, and select per row using a ViewBinder.

```
Within MyActivity.onCreate() {
...
cursorAdapter.setViewBinder(myViewBinder),
...
}
```

And somewhere you implement your ViewBinder like this...

```
private final ViewBinder myViewBinder=new ViewBinder() {
  @Override
  public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
    if(columnIndex==INDEX_OF_THUMB) {
      int id=cursor.get("_id");
      // get thumb-image data for id from somewhere
      // and display in view
    }
};
```

Hope this helps.